# Error compiling less stylesheet with VS 2013 Web Essentials when importing a stylesheet from different folder

Tags: css, less, web-essentials

I am working in VS 2013 update 2 and have recently installed web essentials for  VS 2013 update 2.

My LESS files are spread into a number LESS stylesheets for each page.I am facing errors for @import declaration for URLs say like:
"~/content/fontawesome/font-awesome.less"

It errors out :

```
/*

Compilation Error. 
See error list for details
FileError: '~/content/fontawesome/font-awesome.less' wasn't found

*/
```

It seems Web essentials currently doesn't support compilation of files imported from different folder.

Any suggestions or solutions on how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Omitting `url()` in your `@import` should work.

```
@import "~/content/fontawesome/font-awesome.less";
```

Github issue: [LESS compiling doesn't seem to handle a relative path correctly #134](https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials2013/issues/134)